# Why does inherited public method manipulate the super class's private property instead of the child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, private, public

In the code below, when I run Test2, why does it print `null` instead `lol`? It seems that the `config` method modifies the `a` property of class `Test` instead of `Test2`.

But what's the meaning of inheriting the public methods which manipulate private properties then, why did they design Java like this?

EDIT:

Class `Test` shall not be modified. What I want to do is to reuse the `config` method. I define a private property `a` for `Test2`, but `config` just ignores it and uses the one of `Test`. Shouldn't a method use the property of the class it is in instead of that of the inherited super class?

```
public class Test {
    private String a;

    public void config() {
        a = "lol"
    }
}

public class Test2 extends Test {
    private String a;

    public void print() {
        config();
        System.out.println(a);
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       print()
    }
}
```

Comment: *Because* it's inherited.

Comment: The `config` method *is* using the property of the class that it's in, and it *is* in the superclass. It would not be good if you could break encapsulation by letting a method in the superclass manipulate private fields in a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is, in short, encapsulation. You don't need to, and can't, access something that is private from outside of the class. The accepted pattern of doing what you want is with getters/setters:

```
public abstract class Test {
    public void config() {
        setA("lol");
    }

    public abstract void setA(String value);
}

public class Test2 extends Test {
    private String a;

    public void setA(String value) {
        a = value;
    }

    public void print() {
        config();
        System.out.println(a);
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Test2().print();
    }
}
```

Comment: No this is not what I want to do. What I really want to do is to use the `config` method to change `Test2`'s property `a`. The method `config` has been inherited by class `Test2` right, then the private property `a` it changes should be the one of `Test2`, isn't this the natural thing to happen?

Comment: @shady No, because `a` belongs to `Test2`, and there's nothing you can do to access it from `Test` other than exposing a getter/setter for it. I've edited my answer to do what you want. Note that `Test` is `abstract`.

Comment: In my case, class `Test` shall not be modified. I know property `a` of class `Test` cannot be accessed by class `Test2`. But I want to reuse the `config` method and I define a private property `a` for class `Test2` to do that. But `config` still uses the property `a` of `Test`.

Comment: @shady What you want to do cannot be done if you can't change `Test` at all. You cannot override fields in Java, which is why you have to override getters/setters instead.

Comment: Does it mean that though `Test2` has inherited method `config`, it does not have a copy of the method `config`. If the child class want to use the property `a`, that means `a` should be inherited from the super class `Test`, and that leads to the change of `Test`.

Comment: @shady Yes, you can think of it that way.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the config method modifies the a property of class `Test` instead of `Test2`.

That's right.

> why does it print `null` instead `lol`?

You have two variables with the same name. One is in the superclass `Test`, another is in the subclass `Test2`. Both are named `a` but they refer to different things.

The method `config()` in the superclass references the superclass `a` and the `print()` method in the subclass references the subclass `a`. Since the variables are private, neither method can see the variable in the other class.

> why did they design Java like this?

This is the nature of `private`. Nobody else can see it.

It looks to me like you actually desired the behavior of a `protected` variable:

```
public class Test {
    protected String a;

    public void config() {
        a = "lol"
    }
}

public class Test2 extends Test {
    public void print() {
        config();
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Test2().print();
    }
}
```

This will print `lol`.